MacOS Examples hard link vs soft link in ln -s and link
Please provide some solid MacOS examples of hard link vs soft link in ln -s vs link?
Is a hard link basically just a copy, whereas a soft link links to the original source?
Very confused.

This is not macOS specific, see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9575/424216 and https://serverfault.com/q/10543 .

It's also worth saying that a simple web search brings a lot of pages with this explanation.

You’ve already got three great answers - what’s the problem you’re facing or trying to solve. This seems very likely to be an XY type problem

A hard link is essentially a second catalog entry for the same data. If you delete the original 'file' (e.g. the catalog entry for the data), then the hard link still points to the data. Moving the original file does not break the link.
A soft or symbolic link is a reference to a filepath. (Similar to an Alias in the Finder.) If you delete or move the target, then the link doesn't work anymore.
Hard links can't link to directories/folders; nor to files on different volumes.
Soft links can link to directories and to different volumes.
Analogy time
Imagine a house on the corner of two streets. It could be addressed as Number 1, Delaney Avenue, and Number 1, Station Drive.
These are hard links. You can use either one. If Delaney Avenue gets renamed or renumbered, then the other address will still work.
A symbolic link is a piece of paper on the door saying "Please deliver post next door." If the house next door isn't there, the link doesn't work.

is a hard link just a "nick name" - to the same file? or is it a copy?

@ina It is another pointer to the same data. It is not a duplicate of the data. As in my analogy: different addresses for the same house.

i sort of get that but in your analogy, if the house on Delaney Avenue doesn't exist, then the hard link on Station Drive doesn't work either - same as the soft link?

is it more like universal tracked DNA?

@ina Yes, but it's unlikely that the catalog entries for a file would remain if the data had somehow been deleted. (That's where the analogy breaks down.) I don't know what you mean about DNA. Anyway, I've described it as best I can.

Hard Links
When a hard link is created the following happens.

A filename is entered in a directory.
A reference (pointer) is created from this entry to a file. The file has to reside on the same device (drive) as the directory.
A reference counter associated with the file is incremented.


It is important to note the reference counter is stored with respect to the file and not with respect to the filename.

When a file is first created and a filename is specified, a hard link is made. You can then use the ln or link command to create additional hard links to a file. The rm command removes a filename from directory and decrements the reference counter associated with the corresponding file. When the reference counter reaches zero, the file is deleted, unless some processes still have the file opened. In such cases, the file is deleted when all processes have closed the file.
Soft Links
Soft links are themselves files. All files have an integer associated with them, where certain bits are used to indicate the type of file. A regular file and a symbolic link are differentiated by whether bit 9 (the first bit being bit 0) of this integer is set. When set, the file is treated as a symbolic link. Normally, a symbolic link contains a qualified filename. When a soft link is encountered, the contents of the soft link can be used in an attempt to find the desired file.
To be clear, anything stored in a regular file could be stored in a symbolic link, including binary data. However, there is no reason to store anything other than a filename with or without a path.

i'm confused where some sources say link is a hard link and ln is a soft link?

ina: Both link and ln are the names commands. Each command is a binary executable file. In this case, both files have identical contents. In other words, cmp /bin/ln /bin/link will output nothing. Therefore, both commands need to look at the name use to invoke the command to see if it is supposed to be link or ln. The ln command can create hard and soft links, whereas the link command can only create hard links.
